# Code chunk and output side by side in xaringan slide

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I tried to follow this [tutorial][1] but my code did not work. I would like to have my code chunk and the output side by side within my xaringan slide and rmarkdown files. I am also new to using the xaringan package. I have tried to search for other sources but everything is in regards to images and code, I am interested in making all my code and output the same layout. I tried the code below for my slides but the default format still outputted with knitr. I would also like to have the same layout for my other RMarkdown files that are not presentations. I would appreciate any help and thank you in advance. Also if there is any other information missing please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your YAML block at the top. When I knit the following code, I get a slide with code left, output right. One of the css files may be missing `.pull-left[]` and `.pull-right[]`.

````
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
---

.pull-left[
```{r upload dat, paged.print=FALSE, eval=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
df = cars
as_tibble(df) 
df2 = df # store original data to use for chi-square
```
] 

.pull-right[
```{r upload dat-out, ref.label="upload dat", echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
```
]
````

Comment: Easiest way to confirm would be to search the "hygge" and "robot-fonts" css files for ".pull-left".

Comment: You can also add your own css to one of those files, or better, to your own custom css file. Another option is to give the xaringanthemer package a try.